# Objective-C Fast Enumeration: checking for BOOL

Tags: objective-c, xcode, fast-enumeration

**Scenario** = I need to loop through an array and find how many "unread" there are and count how many to display to the user.

**What I'm Looking For** = something *like* this (this is not my real code)

```
for (NSDictionary *dic in self.objects) {

    [unreadCountArray addObject:dic[@"wasRead"]];

    for (YES in unreadCountArray) {

        //statements

    }
}
```

**Question** = Does anyone know how to loop through and find all of the YES booleans?

Comment: What is "TRUE booleans"? The question as posed is un-answerable.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
NSPredicate *predicate = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"wasRead = YES"];
NSArray *arr = [array filteredArrayUsingPredicate:predicate];
```

Can sort a thousand objects in `0.0004` seconds.

Then just do:

```
for (NSDictionary *object in arr) {
    //Statements
}
```

**Edit:** actually after further experimentation, using fast-enumeration is about four times faster, about `0.0001`, which if scaled to 100000 objects can be much, much faster.

```
NSMutableArray *test = [NSMutableArray array];

for (NSDictionary *dict in array)
    if ([dict[@"theKey"] boolValue])
        [test addObject:dict];
```

So for sorting, fast-enumeration is actually faster but for just a couple hundred objects, the performance increase is negligible.

And please before asking questions like this and getting downvotes, those could have been completely avoided by checking the documentation. Like [this article](https://developer.apple.com/library/Mac/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSPredicate_Class/Reference/NSPredicate.html) and [this article.](https://developer.apple.com/library/Mac/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/Predicates/predicates.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40001789)

Answer (score 2):

If you have an array of dictionaries, and you want to filter them, then `filteredArrayUsingPredicate:` is the method to use.

You can create a predicate using the key from your dictionary (`predicateWithFormat:`).

This will then give you an array of dictionaries that match the conditions in your predicate.

No sample code, I'm answering this on a phone.

Comment: Aight give me moment while I attempt this wizardry.

Comment: `NSPredicate` is good for readability and small arrays but fast-enumeration is actually faster.

Comment: I'd go for readability over performance every time, until I had a measurable, important performance problem.